# Manatee.Trello : Empty Label .Name and .Color Properties

Tags: manatee.trello

Have been using Trello and the Trello Rest API for past several years. A few days ago I began using Manatee.Trello v1.18.1 with .NET Framework 4.5.2 for development of a command line tool.

I used the following...

```
    private static void displayBoardLabels(Board board)
    {
        foreach (Label label in board.Labels)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Id=[{0}], Name=[{1}], Color=[{2}]", label.Id, label.Name, label.Color);
        }
    }
```

...to successfully display the Label Id, Name and Color properties available for a Board, but when I attempted to display the .Name and .Color properties for Labels returned from a Card...

```
    private static void displayCardLabels(Card card)
    {
        foreach (Label label in card.Labels)
        {
            // Valid label.Id is shown, but label.Name and label.Color properties are blank.
            Console.WriteLine("Id=[{0}], Name=[{1}], Color=[{2}]", label.Id, label.Name, label.Color);
        }
    }
```

...the label.Id value was valid, but the .Name and .Color properties were blank.

So my question is, what would cause the .Name and .Color properties for a Label to be blank?

Comment: It may be the updated version.  I changed how properties are specified for download, and Label data may not be flowing.  I'll create a test locally and check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Manatee.Trello.  The labels weren't downloading the additional information.

The fix ([v1.18.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Manatee.Trello/1.18.2)) is now available.